# Displaying data retrieved through GraphQL in a Django website

Tags: django, api, graphql

(Disclaimer : I'm just getting started with Django, and with web dev in general)

I have a backend app that stores different kinds of resources. Some are public and some are private. The application is accessible only to identified users. A GraphQL API allows me to access the resources.

On another server, I'd like to create a website that will be accessible to everyone. I want to use Django to create it.

The website will display a list of resources tagged as "public" in the backend app, with a pagination system and, say, 20 resources by page. The CSS will differ from the backend app and there will be a search section.

From what I understand, I should be able to retrieve the data through the GraphQL API, but I'm a bit confused here. All the documentation and tutos I can find about Django and GraphQL seem to be about setting up a GraphQL API server with Django. All I want to do is to build custom queries and to display them on my different html pages.

How can I do that? Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

You should connect your project with a GraphQL client. As per my research, I have found that there are implementations and examples for graphene-mongoengine in Flask (Flask has a direct GraphQL client).

[Mongoengine Flask with GraphQL Tutorial](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-mongo/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst)

[For Django you can check this out](https://pypi.org/project/python-graphql-client/)

Edit- I was able to get the data from my database with [python-graphql-client](https://pypi.org/project/python-graphql-client/). Now I am able to display them in my template.

Let me know if this helps