# How to properly format data retrieved through GraphQL API into a data frame?

Tags: python, json, api, graphql

This is a follow-up to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086244/displaying-data-retrieved-through-graphql-in-a-django-website).

Following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/connecting-to-a-graphql-api-using-python-246dda927840), I'm trying to get data from a GraphQL API and format the result into a data frame.

Here is my Python script (URL is obfuscated):

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd 

url = 'https://mygraphqlserver.com/graphql/'
query = """{ resources { edges { node { id creatorPerson { firstName }} } } }"""
r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query})
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
resources_dict = json_data['data']['resources']['edges']
resources_output = pd.DataFrame(resources_dict)
print(resources_output)
```

Here is `r.text`:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "resources": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "file/pt0u8h901qni3d",
            "creatorPerson": {
              "firstName": "Jérémy"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "file/f218c8wn4onncj",
            "creatorPerson": {
              "firstName": "Jérémy"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "file/i1y7pjk7a6xy2d",
            "creatorPerson": {
              "firstName": "Jérémy"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the ouput of `print(resources_output)` in the terminal:

```sh
node
0 {'id': 'file/pt0u8h901qni3d', 'creatorPerson':...
1 {'id': 'file/f218c8wn4onncj', 'creatorPerson':...
2 {'id': 'file/i1y7pjk7a6xy2d', 'creatorPerson':......
```

As you can see, I don't succeed to get a proper data frame as I expected (as shown in the tutorial).

Any idea how I can I improve my script to get a properly formatted output?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests import json import os

user = os.getenv("USERNAME") 
key = os.getenv("KEY") 
pwd = os.getenv("PASSWORD")

endpoint = f"https://pkg-graphql-api.*****.com/{user}" 
headers = {"Authorization": f"Basic {key}"}

query = {
    IPublications(abstract: "metabolics") {    
        ICitedBy(filterByYear_lte: 2020) {
            isbn
            count
            pkgId
            normalizedTitle
            IPublishedInConferenceInstanceIds
        }
    } 
}

r = requests.post(endpoint, json={"query": query}, headers=headers) 
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2)) 
else:
    raise Exception(f"Query failed to run with a {r.status_code}{r.text}.")
```

Comment: please fix the formatting of your code